# User Group folder access 2012 essentials

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, users

I am setting up a 2012 r2 essentials box and have a user group setup with access to certain folders.  When I view a user in that group it shows the folder access as nothing.

Is this just a default display (and the folders are actually set correctly) or have I missed something?

I don't have many users so it wouldn't be too much work to remove them all and add them again with no group settings applied.

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

> have a user group setup with access to certain folders.
>   Please provide more information about this operation/configuration, or, relate screenshot if possible.

If you mean add server folder via Dashboard, you may check the user permission on this folder via below ways:
1.  Dashboard – USERS – select specific user account and open Properties – Shared folders tab.
2.  Open Propertied of this server folder using File Explorer.

Best Regards,
Eve Wang